# Taskbar app Jump List Storage Location

Tags: windows, windows-10

When a Taskbar icon is right-clicked, a drop-down occurs that contains a Jump List with pinned file shortcuts (in this case 5 .pdf files) (see below).

Where on the hard drive is this list/Jump List stored?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOeXB.jpg]

Comment: On my machine, I have to go to %APPDATA%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent Items\ . . . . ..  There are no folders under Recent Items named AutomaticDestinations or CustomDestinations.

Also, as it is not intuitive, is there any way of determining which file belongs to which jump list?

Answer (score 1):

The application based jump lists use the following location: `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations`. Pinned items are stored here: `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations\`

But as you can see its not intuitive to determine which file belongs to which jump list entry. If you want to disable them from showing up, in the search windows box type `jump list', its in system settings. Uncheck 'Show recently opened items in Jump Lists on Start or the taskbar'.

Comment: On my machine, I have to go to %APPDATA%\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent Items.  There are no folders named AutomaticDestinations or CustomDestinations.  As it is not intuitive, is there any way of determining which file belongs to which jump list?

Comment: %APPDATA% for my machine maps to C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming , but yes, its under Roaming.. I'm not aware of any way to determine which files belong to which jump list item. I opened one in sublime and it is binary data.

Comment: @omencat, this is not a location of jumplist in windows 10. Delete all items and check the jumplist in taskbar icons (right-click); all still there.